# Using Date as Array

Tags: php, arrays, date

Is there any ways to use DATE in PHP as array. I need to achieve something as below: 
`$date_array = (1-Jan => 'A', 2-Jan => 'B', 3-Jan => 'C', .... so on)`

Is it possible?

Comment: what type of date do you want to use as indices? DateTime Objects? Date Strings?

Comment: Date strings will be used as the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually:

```
$array['1-Jan'] = 'A';
$array['2-Jan'] = 'B';
...
```

Or with a loop:

```
$array = array();
$currentDate = strtotime('2010-01-01');
$totalDays = 365;
for ($i=0; $i<$totalDays; $i++) {
  $array[date('j-M', $currentDate)] = $i;
  $currentDate = strtotime("+1 day", $currentDate);
}
```

Comment: In addition to this, can you suggest any idea to display 3 single arrays into a table?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual specifies that only string and integer can be used as keys for assoc. arrays, but date returns a string, so they should be fine, but to retrive the values back would be a bit messy.

What about something like:

```
$arr = Array(
'A'=>date('Y-m-d', time()),
'B'=>date('Y-m-d', time()-(7 * 24 * 60 * 60))
);

echo in_array(date('Y-m-d'), $arr);
```

That echos "1".

My mistake, you would need to use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) instead of in_array() so you get the array key:

```
echo array_search(date('Y-m-d'), $arr);
```

Ouputs "A".